# Why doesn't Eclipse always install my APK?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using the Android plugin for Eclipse on OSX, latest versions of everything. When I run or debug my app, Eclipse is very inconsistent about uploading/installing the new APK. Nothing I seem to do has any effect on this. Clean builds, debug, whatever, there seems to be about 50/50 chance of installing the APK. Or not. If not, then I have to kill the emulator and try again. What is going in?

Comment: Are there any error messages, either in the Eclipse Console, or from logcat?

Comment: No, that would be too easy. The console will print the usual warning: 

[2010-01-13 16:53:47 - Emulator]2010-01-13 16:53:47.895 emulator[2219:903] Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.

Nothing (seemingly) relevant in LogCat, i.e. no errors/warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

then you in that state try from terminal adb kill-server then adb devices

Comment: I noticed that my device did not appear in DDMS, so I think this is what was going on. Restarting adb, then re-running app seems to work. Wish I knew why this was happening in the first place.

Comment: Also, you can do this from inside Eclipse. Go to DDMS. In the Devices window, there is a drop down menu (upside down triangle, with "View Menu" as its tooltip). Click on that and at the bottom there is a Reset adb option that does the above.